# An inconsistency in beamer color handling: how to set color for a specific slide layer?

Tags: beamer, macros

The following MWE works for setting the color of the bullets, but not the `\item` text (except at the top level, which turns everything grey). As I step through the slides, I'd like the text of the active "major point" (top level item) to be black.

```
\documentclass[compress,red,notes]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\frame{
\frametitle{Test color transition in beamer enumerations}

{\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=gray}
\setbeamercolor{itemize/enumerate body}{fg=gray!65}
\begin{itemize}
  {\only<1>{\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=red}
            \setbeamercolor{itemize/enumerate body}{fg=black}}
  \item Major point 1
  \begin{itemize}
    \scriptsize
    \item Minor point 1
    \item Minor point 2
  \end{itemize}
  } % end of \only<1>
  {\only<2>{\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=red}
            \setbeamercolor{itemize/enumerate body}{fg=black}}
  \item Major point 2
  \begin{itemize}
    \scriptsize
    \item Minor point 1
    \item Minor point 2
  \end{itemize}
  } % end of \only<2>
  {\only<3>{\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=red}
            \setbeamercolor{itemize/enumerate body}{fg=black}}
  \item Major point 3
  \begin{itemize}
    \scriptsize
    \item Minor point 1
    \item Minor point 2
  \end{itemize}
  } % end of \only<3>
  {\only<4>{\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=red}
            \setbeamercolor{itemize/enumerate body}{fg=black}}
  \item Major point 4
  \begin{itemize}
    \scriptsize
    \item Minor point 1
    \item Minor point 2
  \end{itemize}
  } % end of \only<4>
\end{itemize}
} % end of \color{gray}
} % end of \frame

\end{document}
```

Assuming this can be made to work, it would also be nice to put the `\only<x>{ ... }` code in its own command. I'm a bit confused about the difference between `\command<parameter>{main param}` (as seen in `\only<parameter>{...}` and `\command[parameter]{main param}` (as seen in almost all other commands outside of beamer). What is the difference between < > and [ ]?

Comment: `<>` are overlay specifications specific to beamer; `[]` are where options to a command are specified. See the [beamer docs](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), Pg. 78 in v3.33 for more information about the `<>`

Comment: Thanks - I tried implementing this command to make things simpler, but I believe there is a scope issue with `\setbeamercolor` being called within a command: `\newcommand{\itemOnly}[1]{\only<#1>{%
\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=gray}%
\setbeamercolor{itemize/enumerate body}{fg=gray!65}%
}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use the `\alert` command:

```
\documentclass[compress,show notes]{beamer}
\colorlet{myred}{red!70!black}
\usecolortheme[named=myred]{structure}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}

\frame{
  \frametitle{Test color transition in beamer enumerations}
  {%
    \setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=gray}
    \setbeamercolor{itemize/enumerate body}{fg=gray!65}
    \setbeamertemplate{alerted text begin}{%
      \setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=red}\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=black}
    }
    \begin{itemize}
      \alert<1>{\item Major point 1
      \begin{itemize}
        \scriptsize
        \item Minor point 1
        \item Minor point 2
      \end{itemize}}
      \alert<2>{\item Major point 2
      \begin{itemize}
        \scriptsize
        \item Minor point 1
        \item Minor point 2
      \end{itemize}}
      \alert<3>{\item Major point 3
      \begin{itemize}
        \scriptsize
        \item Minor point 1
        \item Minor point 2
      \end{itemize}}
      \alert<4>{\item Major point 4
      \begin{itemize}
        \scriptsize
        \item Minor point 1
        \item Minor point 2
      \end{itemize}}
    \end{itemize}
  }
}
\end{document}
```

Note that the class options `red` and `note` are obsolete in version 3.33 Use the color theme `structure` and the option `show notes` instead.

The `<>` contains the overlay specifications.

[image]

Comment: This does indeed solve both issues. Thanks for the points on obsolescence.